# How to execute a function after a handlebars helper has been rendered

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

How can I get a a function to execute everytime after this Handlebars helper is executed?

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('renderPage', function() {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('currentPage')]());
});
```

This is running in Meteor, I have a router that sets a new 'currentPage' in Session, as Session is reactive this renders the template that I set with 'currentpage'.

I could do it by using a template with a content element, and then use Template.templateName.rendered, but this does not work for me, as I want this as a package and I by now think, that you can't put templates into meteorite packages.

If yes I could just do:

```
Template.renderPage.content = function {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('currentPage')]());
});

Template.renderPage.rendered = function () { ... }
```

Comment: Set a session var is a workaround. Don't think there is an after hook for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function to run every time that helper is run, why not just define it as part of the helper?

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('renderPage', function() {
    var ret = new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('currentPage')]());
    someFunctionYouWantToRun();
    return ret;
});
```

More broadly, if you want your function and helper to run on every page change, create a root-level template that contains the others and then attach it to that page's .rendered():

within **index.html**:

```
<body>
  {{> root}}
</body>
```

within **root.html**:

```
<template name="root">
{{#if CurrentPageIsHome}}
  {{> home}}
{{/if}}
</template>
```

within **root.js**:

```
Template.root.currentPageIsHome = function() {
  return Session.equals("currentPage", "home");
}

Template.root.rendered = function() {
  // Code you want run on every template render of root and every subtemplate
}
```

Better still, use the [Meteor Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) package.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good! I managed to do it with my solution. The Root template was basically the solution. Defining the function as part of the helper was not possible, as I wanted to manipulate the DOM after the helper has rendered.

I am acutally using the router, but I want a wildcard router /sometemplate, as this is for UI prototyping and should just be fast.

Comment: See also Meteor Router's route functions: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router#route-functions. It enables you to create paths like example.com/posts/1234 (where 1234 is a wildcard for an ID). The wildcard handling is very flexible and can probably handle any variation you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

So what's working for me, is to use a template instead of a helper. To make this templates work from a meteorite package I had to wrap them in a Meteor.startup function otherwise it wouldn't fine the Template.

```
Template.renderPage.content = function {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('currentPage')]());
});

Template.renderPage.rendered = function () { ... }
```

And then I use Template.xxx.rendered function for an after hook.